# eventReactive recalculates already calculated objects with unchanged input

Tags: r, caching, shiny, lazy-loading, shiny-reactivity

As I understand, `eventReactive` (or any reactive function) should not recalculate stuff whose related input did not change, but this is what's happening in my case. I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong but I just don't know what. In essence, I have two `eventReactive` functions, one involves a very time-consuming calculation, and the other mainly just plotting (should be quite quick). However, even when I change some inputs for plotting, the first `eventReactive` function is executed too (even though it's not needed).

Here is a shortened version of my code:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
    res_tabl <-
        eventReactive(c(input$recalc, input$recalc2), # this is a time-consuming calculation
                      ignoreNULL = FALSE, {
                          prep_sim(
                              gg_start = input$gg_start,
                              gg_end = input$gg_end
                          )
                      })
    threeplots <-
        eventReactive(c(input$recalc, input$recalc2), # this is for plotting
                      ignoreNULL = FALSE, {
                          prep_plot(
                              results_to_plot = res_tabl(),
                              yval_opt = input$yval_opt
                          )
                      })

    output$esdc_plot_comb <- renderPlot({
        threeplots()[[1]]
    })
    output$esdc_plot_tot <- renderPlotly({
        threeplots()[[2]]
    })
    output$esdc_plot_comb2 <- renderPlot({
        threeplots()[[1]]
    })
    output$esdc_plot_tot2 <- renderPlotly({
        threeplots()[[2]]
    })
    output$esdc_table <- renderDataTable({
        res_tabl()
    })
}
```

What should I do so that when I press a single Action button and I only changed `input$yval_opt`, only the second `eventReactive` content would run? (Nothing should run until I click the button.)

Less importantly – and perhaps this should be a separate question – as you can see I render each of the two returned plots twice. Is there perhaps a more efficient way to do this?

(The full code is available [here](https://github.com/gasparl/esdi/blob/master/app.R).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was tricky.

- To avoid automatic calculation at App start-up, you should set ignoreNULL = T
- This works on a single condition, but [not on multiple conditions using c(recalc1,recalc2)](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/2097) 
  Solution is :

```
eventReactive(req(isTruthy(input$recalc1) | isTruthy(input$recalc2)), ignoreNULL = T,...
```

- Added a reactiveVal() to keep track of last calculation update

I think following Minimal Reproducible example responds to your needs :

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI 
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Test"),

    # Sidebar with a slider inpust 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput("vizslider",
                        "viz percentage:",
                        min = 1,
                        max = 100,
                        value = 30),
            sliderInput("calcslider",
                        "Calculation duration (s):",
                        min = 1,
                        max = 10,
                        value = 2),
            actionButton("recalc1", "Calc 1"),
            actionButton("recalc2", "Calc 2"),
        ),

        # Show result
        mainPanel(
           textOutput("result")
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic 
server <- function(input, output) {
    lastcalc <- reactiveVal(0)
    run <- reactive({})
    calcresult <- eventReactive(req(isTruthy(input$recalc1) | isTruthy(input$recalc2)), ignoreNULL = T, {
        if (lastcalc()==input$calcslider)  {return("last calculation")} else {lastcalc(input$calcslider)}
        cat("Start calc for ",input$calcslider, "seconds\n")
        Sys.sleep(input$calcslider)
        cat("End calc \n")
        paste("calculation done in",input$calcslider,"seconds")

    })

    output$result <- eventReactive(c(input$recalc1,input$recalc2), ignoreNULL = T, {
       req(calcresult())
       paste("filter",input$vizslider,"% of a ",calcresult())
    })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Okay but that would need two separate buttons. I want a single button that executes either only the second part or both, depending on whether the input changed for the first part.

Comment: To clarify: `input$recalc` and `input$recalc2` are identical buttons at different parts of the page.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification : can you simplify your question to reduce it to a minimal reproducible example? I think that recalc & recalc2 add an unneeded confusion

Comment: Okay +1 for sensible workaround, but this is still not really the answer. Again, I'd want all changes in one click.

Comment: (If I reduce the example further, someone might give an answer that's not applicable to my case.)

Comment: The solution I provide does following : when you push recalc, everything (calculation + plot) is updated  = 1 click. If there is a modification to input$[anything], the plot recalculates without launching the long calculation. I don't get your point one only one click, what do you expect more?

Comment: Plots should not be recreated before the click. See my very first comment here.

Comment: OK, I think I get it, what about req(res_tabl), see my edit

Comment: Well it doesn't work for me. Plots are still updates even if I don't click. I suppose `res_table` is available already from previous runs

Comment: wow, quite a workaround, but yeah, the result is exactly what I wanted. Nice, thank you.